# T-SQL - Select results from latest academic year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that when joined with a datetime can return the academic year
so the result will look like this

```
ID |          Date           | Academic year
----------------------------------------------
1  | 2020-11-09 00:00:00.000 |   2020/21 
----------------------------------------------
2  | 2021-01-10 00:00:00.000 |   2020/21
----------------------------------------------
3  | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 |   2019/20
```

What I am after is to only return the results in the latest/current academic year. Please note that academic year is not a date datatype so that rules out all the date functions. I don't want to just use "2020/21" in the where clause because of course the academic year will change in September.

I am using SSMS version 15

Comment: What are the business rules you use to determine the current academic year?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. "Please note that academic year is not a date datatype" is a nice teaser. Why not share what the data types are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause that checks if the current month is 9 or greater because this is the condition that distinguishes the academic years:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE YEAR(GETDATE()) = CAST(LEFT(Academic_year, 4) AS INTEGER) + 
                        CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) >= 9 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

If the current month is 9 or greater then the current year must be equal to the first 4 chars of `Academic_year`.
It it is less than 9 then the current year must be equal to the first 4 chars of `Academic_year` + 1.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c194672e8da8348c06730421057945bf).

Comment: Hi @forpas, thank you for that, it seems to work! Are you able to unpick your cast/case a bit more to explain what is going on for my benefit?

Comment: @user3513098 When you run this code in Sep, Oct, Nov or Dec the CASE expression returns 0. In any other month it returns 1. So in Sep, Oct, Nov or Dec the WHERE clause compares the current year to the integer number which is represented by the first 4 chars of Academic_year but for the other months it compares it to that year + 1. For example in April 2021 the Academic_year is 2020/21 so the comparison of the current year must be with 2021 = 2020(first 4 chars) + 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE SUBSTRING([Academic year], 1, 4) = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy')
```

If the Academic year starts in September then you will need something more like this:

```
DECLARE @AccYearParm VARCHAR(7) = '2020/08';
SELECT * FROM [TableName] WHERE SUBSTRING([Academic year], 1, 7) > @AccYearParm
```

Comment: I don't think that will give row 2 which is in the academic year

Comment: That has returned nothing unfortunately

Comment: @user3513098, Please check my latest edit, I believe it is because you are still in the 2020 accedemic year?

Comment: @PeterSmith, you are right about the 1st query, I thought that was sample data, but it actually indicates the current academic year which is 2020.

Comment: @Nemavhidi That does work in a way, but after next year it will still return 2020/21 results when we are in the 2021/22 ac year.